# TreeSet Comparator

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

I have a TreeSet and a custom comparator. 
I get the values from server according to the changes in the stock

ex: if time=0 then server will send all the entries on the stock (unsorted)
  if time=200 then server will send entries added or deleted after the time 200(unsorted)

In client side i am sorting the entries. My question is which is more efficient

1> fetch all entries first and then call addAll method
or
2> add one by one

there can be millions of entries.

/////////updated///////////////////////////////////

```
  private static Map<Integer, KeywordInfo> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, KeywordInfo>();
  private static Set<Integer> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Integer>(comparator);

      private static final Comparator<Integer> comparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
          int integerCompareValue = o1.compareTo(o2);
          if (integerCompareValue == 0) return integerCompareValue;
          KeywordInfo k1 = hashMap.get(o1);
          KeywordInfo k2 = hashMap.get(o2);
          if (null == k1.getKeyword()) {
            if (null == k2.getKeyword())
              return integerCompareValue;
            else
              return -1;
          } else {
            if (null == k2.getKeyword())
              return 1;
            else {
              int compareString = AlphaNumericCmp.COMPARATOR.compare(k1.getKeyword().toLowerCase(), k2.getKeyword().toLowerCase());
              //int compareString =  k1.getKeyword().compareTo(k2.getKeyword());
              if (compareString == 0)
                return integerCompareValue;
              return compareString;
            }
          }
        }
      };
```

now there is an event handler which gives me an ArrayList of updated entries,
after adding them to my hashMap i am calling

```
final Map<Integer, KeywordInfo> mapToReturn = new SubMap<Integer, KeywordInfo>(sortedSet, hashMap);
```

Comment: It's not clear whether you are sorting *subsets* and intend to call `treeSet.addAll(subsetA); ... treeSet.addAll(subsetN);`, or actually want to add all (unsorted) elements to the tree set *in order to* sort them.

Comment: It's still not clear what your "event handler" does and when it is called. Regardless of that: If the question is *only* about performance for this particular case, I'd recommend to implement both versions and run a benchmark.

Comment: And a profiler. Those `.toLowerCase()`s could hurt (do them on creation of `KeywordInfo`).

Answer (score 1):

I think your bottleneck can be probably more network-related than CPU related. A bulk operation fetching all the new entries at once would be more network efficient.

With regards to your CPU, the time required to populate a TreeSet does not change consistently between multiple add()s and addAll(). The reason behind is that TreeSet relies on AbstractCollection's addAll() (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) which in turn creates an iterator and calls multiple times add().

So, my advice on the CPU side is: choose the way that keeps your code cleaner and more readable. This is probably obtained through addAll().

Comment: The `TreeSet` actually contains a special treatment that allows *linear* time of `addAll` for certain cases (although this is most likely not applicable here). For "millions" of entries, this could actually make a difference, compared to O(nlogn). However, you're right that this will most likely not be the bottleneck here.

Comment: @Marco13 That's an interesting point. You could sort on the server, "fake" a `SortedSet` and add that to the `TreeSet`. Even on the client side, a sort on an array could be faster than going straight to a tree (though the comparator here looks inefficient).

Comment: As it performance should be I/O dominated, overlapping I/O and computational time could reduce latency mildly. But, yeah, it's invariably better to get something that is cleaning, working and thoroughly tested before optimising.

Answer (score 0):

The actual implementation is a linked list, so add one by one will be faster if you do it right. And i think in the near future this behaviour wont be change.

For your problem a Statefull comparator may help.

```
// snipplet, must not work fine
public class NaturalComparator implements Comparator{
    private boolean anarchy = false;
    private Comparator parentComparator;

    NaturalComparator(Comparator parent){
       this.parentComparator = parent;
    }
    public void setAnarchy(){...}
    public int compare(A a, A b){
      if(anarchy) return 1
      else return parentCoparator.compare(a,b);
    }
}
...
Set<Integer> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Integer>(new NaturalComparator(comparator));
comparator.setAnarchy(true);
sortedSet.addAll(sorted);
comparator.setAnarchy(false);
```

Comment: i was doing that only but then i saw that on every addition it calls the comparator to compare it with all the existing entries and so i am thinking to call the addAll method...

Comment: Where does a "linked list" come in play here?

Comment: @sumitjain `addAll` will compare everything with everything too! No performance difference here.

Comment: @Marco13 Because of the implementation of `java.util.TreeMap.Entry`. If it would have been saved like a array `Object[100000000]` `addAll` would be faster because we can use `System.arraycopy`.

Comment: This "linked list" behavior would only appear when all elements are equal (acoording to the comparator). If all items are different, then it should indeed be a *tree*, with O(logn) insertion, and O(nlogn) (amortized) for the insertion of n elements. But maybe I misunderstood something here.

Comment: @Marco13 I do not mean the `LinkedList` type. I mean the pattern/design. Like: *Every collection that is not a array is a linked list* (do not kill me for this absolution). Sometimes a list is a double linked list. A tree may have children in a array (in this case i would say) is not linked. But if a Tree has a Parent-Field its a linked list. If a node has a Parent-Field as well as a List of Children, i would say its a double linked list.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is less memory overhead when on being loaded alread data is stored. This should be time efficient too, maybe using small buffers. Memory allocation costs time too.

However time both solutions, in a separate prototype. You really have to test with huge numbers, as network traffic costs much too. That is a bit Test Driven Development, and adds to QA both quantitative statistics, as correctness of implementation.